Наследование классов: неправильный вывод
Столкнулся с проблемой неправильного вывода результата наследуемого метода.
Задача:

Создайте базовый класс Specialist, сохраняющий атрибут экземпляра name имеющий методы drink_coffee, возвращающий строку
"{имя} пьет кофе", и work, возвращающий строку вида "{имя} выполняет работу".
Создайте дочерний класс Coder, наследующий методы и атрибуты класса Specialist, и переопределяющий метод work таким
образом, чтобы он возвращал строку вида "{имя} пишет код".
Создайте дочерний класс ProjectManager, наследующий методы и атрибуты класса Specialist, и переопределяющий метод work
таким образом, чтобы он возвращал строку вида "{имя} управляет проектом".
Создайте класс TeamLeader, наследующий атрибуты и методы классов Coder и ProectManager таким образом, чтобы при вызове
метода work возвращалась строка "{имя} управляет проектом". Проверка этого критерия будет производиться при помощи
инструмента MRO

Мой код:
class Specialist:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    # Метод drink_coffee
    def drink_coffee(self):
        return f"{self.name} пьет кофе"

    # Базовый метод work
    def work(self):
        return f"{self.name} выполняет работу"


# Дочерний класс Coder, наследующий от Specialist
class Coder(Specialist):
    # Переопределяем метод work
    def work(self):
        return f"{self.name} пишет код"


# Дочерний класс ProjectManager, наследующий от Specialist
class ProjectManager(Specialist):
    # Переопределяем метод work
    def work(self):
        return f"{self.name} управляет проектом"


# Класс TeamLeader, наследующий от Coder и ProjectManager
class TeamLeader(Coder, ProjectManager):
    # Переопределять метод work не нужно, он будет взят по MRO из ProjectManager

    pass

Тест который должен проходить:
t = TeamLeader('Василий') 
print(t.work())

Правильный вывод:
Василий управляет проектом
Мой неправильный вывод:
Василий пишет код

Для решения вашей проблемы, нужно сперва разобраться с порядком разрешения методов (method resolution order). MRO - позволяет Python выяснить, из какого класса-предка нужно вызывать метод, если он не обнаружен непосредственно в классе-потомке.
Если распечатаем MRO -> print(TeamLeader.__mro__):
Василий пишет код
(<class '__main__.TeamLeader'>, <class '__main__.Coder'>, <class '__main__.ProjectManager'>, <class '__main__.Specialist'>, <class 'object'>)


TeamLeader -> Coder -> ProjectManager -> Specialist -> object

Что выходит? Сначала ищем метод в классе TeamLeader, затем в Coder, затем в ProjectManager и только потом в Specialist. В данном случае метод work найден в классе Coder, отсюда и результат "Василий пишет код".
Следовательно, что бы получить "Василий управляет проектом", необходимо изменить порядок наследования:
class TeamLeader(ProjectManager, Coder):
    pass

Теперь MRO будет:

TeamLeader -> ProjectManager -> Coder -> Specialist -> object

Таким образом, метод work будет найден в классе ProjectManager, и результат - "Василий управляет проектом".
Василий управляет проектом
(<class '__main__.TeamLeader'>, <class '__main__.ProjectManager'>, <class '__main__.Coder'>, <class '__main__.Specialist'>, <class 'object'>)


Интересно получается. Человек знает про MRO, но не знает про порядок поиска атрибутов и методов классов. Чудеса!

@VladimirBogdanov скорее задание знало про MRO, а вот ТС этой аббревиатуры не знал.

Ставлю + за Ваш ответ. Очень доходчиво. Достоин, чтобы включить в книгу про Python.

Добавить бы ещё расшифровку аббревиатуры MRO в ответ и вообще идеально будет )

@CrazyElf дополнил ответ, надеюсь теперь станет более идеально+))

В качестве академического интереса. Раз TeamLeader наследует и от Coder, и от ProjectManager, то делает работу того и другого.
class Specialist:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def drink_coffee(self):
        return f"{self.name} пьет кофе"

    def work(self):
        return f"{self.name} выполняет работу"


class Coder(Specialist):
    def work(self):
        return f"{self.name} пишет код"


class ProjectManager(Specialist):
    def work(self):
        return f"{self.name} управляет проектом"


class TeamLeader(Coder, ProjectManager):
    def __getattribute__(self, attr):
        match attr:
            case 'work':
                _str = "\n".join(
                    getattr(_cls, attr, lambda _: "")(self)
                    for _cls in self.__class__.__bases__
                )
                return lambda: _str
            case _:
                return super().__getattribute__(attr)


t = TeamLeader("Василий")
print(t.work())

